# Utilizing the "table*" option to span a table across a two-column format results in the loss of the defined table formatting and footnotes

Tags: tables, overleaf

Switching from "table" to "table*" for a specific example table results in a loss of font size and footnotes, as evident in the images below.

[image]

When I apply "table*" to the table above, adding four additional columns while keeping everything else the same, the footnotes disappear, and the font size of the table content changes.

[image]

This issue appears to be unusual, and I'm having difficulty pinpointing the underlying cause. I've included a sample TEX file below for reference. Unfortunately, due to word limit constraints, I'm unable to provide the class file directly. However, you can easily download or test it from this [Overleaf project](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/springer-nature-latex-template/gsvvftmrppwq).

> ```
> TEX File (sn-article.tex)
> ```

```
\documentclass[iicol]{sn-jnl}% Default with double column layout


%%%% Standard Packages
%%<additional latex packages if required can be included here>

\usepackage{graphicx}%
\usepackage{multirow}%
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}%
\usepackage{amsthm}%
\usepackage{mathrsfs}%
\usepackage[title]{appendix}%
\usepackage{xcolor}%
\usepackage{textcomp}%
\usepackage{manyfoot}%
\usepackage{booktabs}%
\usepackage{algorithm}%
\usepackage{algorithmicx}%
\usepackage{algpseudocode}%
\usepackage{listings}%
%%%%%

\raggedbottom
%%\unnumbered% uncomment this for unnumbered level heads

\begin{document}

\title[Article Title]{Article Title}

\abstract{The abstract serves both as a general introduction to the topic and as a brief, non-technical summary of the main results and their implications. Authors are advised to check the author instructions for the journal they are submitting to for word limits and if structural elements like subheadings, citations, or equations are permitted.}

\keywords{keyword1, Keyword2, Keyword3, Keyword4}
\maketitle

\section{Introduction}\label{sec1}

The Introduction section, of referenced text \cite{bib1} expands on the background of the work (some overlap with the Abstract is acceptable). The introduction should not include subheadings.

Springer Nature does not impose a strict layout as standard however authors are advised to check the individual requirements for the journal they are planning to submit to as there may be journal-level preferences. When preparing your text please also be aware that some stylistic choices are not supported in full text XML (publication version), including coloured font. These will not be replicated in the typeset article if it is accepted. 


\section{Tables}\label{sec5}
\begin{table}[b]
\caption{Caption text}\label{tab1}%
\begin{tabular}{@{}llll@{}}
\toprule
Column 1 & Column 2  & Column 3 & Column 4\\
\midrule
row 1    & data 1   & data 2  & data 3  \\
row 2    & data 4   & data 5\footnotemark[1]  & data 6  \\
row 3    & data 7   & data 8  & data 9\footnotemark[2]  \\
\botrule
\end{tabular}
\footnotetext{Source: This is an example of table footnote. This is an example of table footnote.}
\footnotetext[1]{Example for a first table footnote. This is an example of table footnote.}
\footnotetext[2]{Example for a second table footnote. This is an example of table footnote.}
\end{table}

\begin{table*}[t]
\caption{Caption text}\label{tab1}%
\begin{tabular}{@{}llllllll@{}}
\toprule
Column 1 & Column 2  & Column 3 & Column 4 & Column 1 & Column 2  & Column 3 & Column 4\\
\midrule
row 1    & data 1   & data 2  & data 3  & row 1    & data 1   & data 2  & data 3\\
row 2    & data 4   & data 5\footnotemark[1]  & data 6  & row 2    & data 4   & data 5\footnotemark[1]  & data 6 \\
row 3    & data 7   & data 8  & data 9\footnotemark[2]  & & data 7   & data 8  & data 9\footnotemark[2]\\
\botrule
\end{tabular}
\footnotetext{Source: This is an example of table footnote. This is an example of table footnote.}
\footnotetext[1]{Example for a first table footnote. This is an example of table footnote.}
\footnotetext[2]{Example for a second table footnote. This is an example of table footnote.}
\end{table*}

Tables can be inserted via the normal table and tabular environment. To put
footnotes inside tables you should use \verb+\footnotetext[]{...}+ tag.
The footnote appears just below the table itself (refer Tables~\ref{tab1} and \ref{tab2}). 
For the corresponding footnotemark use \verb+\footnotemark[...]+
Tables can be inserted via the normal table and tabular environment. To put
footnotes inside tables you should use \verb+\footnotetext[]{...}+ tag.Tables can be inserted via the normal table and tabular environment. To put
footnotes inside tables you should use \verb+\footnotetext[]{...}+ tag.
The footnote appears just below the table itself (refer Tables~\ref{tab1} and \ref{tab2}). 
For the corresponding footnotemark use \verb+\footnotemark[...]+Tables can be inserted via the normal table and tabular environment. To put
footnotes inside tables you should use \verb+\footnotetext[]{...}+ tag.
The footnote appears just below the table itself (refer Tables~\ref{tab1} and \ref{tab2}). 
For the corresponding footnotemark use \verb+\footnotemark[...]+Tables can be inserted via the normal table and tabular environment. To put
footnotes inside tables you should use \verb+\footnotetext[]{...}+ tag.
The footnote appears just below the table itself (refer Tables~\ref{tab1} and \ref{tab2}). 
For the corresponding footnotemark use \verb+\footnotemark[...]+
Tables can be inserted via the normal table and tabular environment. To put
footnotes inside tables you should use \verb+\footnotetext[]{...}+ tag.Tables can be inserted via the normal table and tabular environment. To put
footnotes inside tables you should use \verb+\footnotetext[]{...}+ tag.
The footnote appears just below the table itself (refer Tables~\ref{tab1} and \ref{tab2}). 
For the corresponding footnotemark use \verb+\footnotemark[...]+Tables can be inserted via the normal table and tabular environment. To put
footnotes inside tables you should use \verb+\footnotetext[]{...}+ tag.
The footnote appears just below the table itself (refer Tables~\ref{tab1} and \ref{tab2}). 
For the corresponding footnotemark use \verb+\footnotemark[...]+

\end{document}
```

Comment: The fact that it worked at all for table is odd.  Document class sn-jnl must be doing someting unusual.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't load sn-jnl.cls (too lazy), but you can achieve the desired effect with article class by putting the entire table into a minipage.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}% Default with double column layout


%%%% Standard Packages
%%<additional latex packages if required can be included here>

\usepackage{graphicx}%
\usepackage{multirow}%
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}%
\usepackage{amsthm}%
\usepackage{mathrsfs}%
\usepackage[title]{appendix}%
\usepackage{xcolor}%
\usepackage{textcomp}%
\usepackage{manyfoot}%
\usepackage{booktabs}%
\usepackage{algorithm}%
\usepackage{algorithmicx}%
\usepackage{algpseudocode}%
\usepackage{listings}%
%%%%%

\raggedbottom
%%\unnumbered% uncomment this for unnumbered level heads

\begin{document}

\title[Article Title]{Article Title}

\abstract{The abstract serves both as a general introduction to the topic and as a brief, non-technical summary of the main results and their implications. Authors are advised to check the author instructions for the journal they are submitting to for word limits and if structural elements like subheadings, citations, or equations are permitted.}

%\keywords{keyword1, Keyword2, Keyword3, Keyword4}
\maketitle

\section{Introduction}\label{sec1}

The Introduction section, of referenced text \cite{bib1} expands on the background of the work (some overlap with the Abstract is acceptable). The introduction should not include subheadings.

Springer Nature does not impose a strict layout as standard however authors are advised to check the individual requirements for the journal they are planning to submit to as there may be journal-level preferences. When preparing your text please also be aware that some stylistic choices are not supported in full text XML (publication version), including coloured font. These will not be replicated in the typeset article if it is accepted. 


\section{Tables}\label{sec5}
\begin{table}[b]
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
\renewcommand{\thempfootnote}{\ifnum\value{mpfootnote}=0 \space\else\arabic{mpfootnote}\fi}
\caption{Caption text}\label{tab1}%
\begin{tabular}{@{}llll@{}}
\toprule
Column 1 & Column 2  & Column 3 & Column 4\\
\midrule
row 1    & data 1   & data 2  & data 3  \\
row 2    & data 4   & data 5\footnotemark[1]  & data 6  \\
row 3    & data 7   & data 8  & data 9\footnotemark[2]  \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\footnotetext{Source: This is an example of table footnote. This is an example of table footnote.}
\footnotetext[1]{Example for a first table footnote. This is an example of table footnote.}
\footnotetext[2]{Example for a second table footnote. This is an example of table footnote.}
\end{minipage}
\end{table}

\begin{table*}[t]
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
\renewcommand{\thempfootnote}{\ifnum\value{mpfootnote}=0 \space\else\arabic{mpfootnote}\fi}
\caption{Caption text}\label{tab1}%
\begin{tabular}{@{}llllllll@{}}
\toprule
Column 1 & Column 2  & Column 3 & Column 4 & Column 1 & Column 2  & Column 3 & Column 4\\
\midrule
row 1    & data 1   & data 2  & data 3  & row 1    & data 1   & data 2  & data 3\\
row 2    & data 4   & data 5\footnotemark[1]  & data 6  & row 2    & data 4   & data 5\footnotemark[1]  & data 6 \\
row 3    & data 7   & data 8  & data 9\footnotemark[2]  & & data 7   & data 8  & data 9\footnotemark[2]\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\footnotetext{Source: This is an example of table footnote. This is an example of table footnote.}
\footnotetext[1]{Example for a first table footnote. This is an example of table footnote.}
\footnotetext[2]{Example for a second table footnote. This is an example of table footnote.}
\end{minipage}
\end{table*}

Tables can be inserted via the normal table and tabular environment. To put
footnotes inside tables you should use \verb+\footnotetext[]{...}+ tag.
The footnote appears just below the table itself (refer Tables~\ref{tab1} and \ref{tab2}). 
For the corresponding footnotemark use \verb+\footnotemark[...]+
Tables can be inserted via the normal table and tabular environment. To put
footnotes inside tables you should use \verb+\footnotetext[]{...}+ tag.Tables can be inserted via the normal table and tabular environment. To put
footnotes inside tables you should use \verb+\footnotetext[]{...}+ tag.
The footnote appears just below the table itself (refer Tables~\ref{tab1} and \ref{tab2}). 
For the corresponding footnotemark use \verb+\footnotemark[...]+Tables can be inserted via the normal table and tabular environment. To put
footnotes inside tables you should use \verb+\footnotetext[]{...}+ tag.
The footnote appears just below the table itself (refer Tables~\ref{tab1} and \ref{tab2}). 
For the corresponding footnotemark use \verb+\footnotemark[...]+Tables can be inserted via the normal table and tabular environment. To put
footnotes inside tables you should use \verb+\footnotetext[]{...}+ tag.
The footnote appears just below the table itself (refer Tables~\ref{tab1} and \ref{tab2}). 
For the corresponding footnotemark use \verb+\footnotemark[...]+
Tables can be inserted via the normal table and tabular environment. To put
footnotes inside tables you should use \verb+\footnotetext[]{...}+ tag.Tables can be inserted via the normal table and tabular environment. To put
footnotes inside tables you should use \verb+\footnotetext[]{...}+ tag.
The footnote appears just below the table itself (refer Tables~\ref{tab1} and \ref{tab2}). 
For the corresponding footnotemark use \verb+\footnotemark[...]+Tables can be inserted via the normal table and tabular environment. To put
footnotes inside tables you should use \verb+\footnotetext[]{...}+ tag.
The footnote appears just below the table itself (refer Tables~\ref{tab1} and \ref{tab2}). 
For the corresponding footnotemark use \verb+\footnotemark[...]+

\end{document}
```