Why footnote text within solution environment is not going to the bottom of the page?
My footnote text in the solution environment is not going at the bottom of the page. While i want it at the bottom of the page. Please anyone can help me regardin this. Thanks in advance.

\documentclass[10pt, a4paper, twoside]{book}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\definecolor{lightblue}{RGB}{226, 234, 250}
\definecolor{titlecolor}{RGB}{32,136,200} % Change this color as desired

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% uebung style start %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%5
\tcolorboxenvironment{uebung}{
 breakable,
  boxrule=0pt,
  boxsep=1pt,
  colback=lightblue!70, 
   sharp corners,
  before skip=10pt,
  after skip=10pt,
  colframe=white,
}
 \newtheoremstyle{uebungstyle}%
  {}% Space above
  {}% Space below
  {}% Body font
  {}% Indent amount
  {\sffamily\bfseries\color{titlecolor}\fontsize{10}{12}\selectfont\setstretch{0.5}}% 
  {}% Punctuation after theorem head
  {\newline}% Space after theorem head
  {}% Theorem head spec
\theoremstyle{uebungstyle}{
  \newtheorem{uebung}{Uebung}[chapter]
}
\mdfdefinestyle{losungstyle}{
    linewidth=0.1pt,
    roundcorner=10pt,
    linecolor=white,
    backgroundcolor=white,
    innertopmargin=10pt,
    innerbottommargin=10pt,
    innerrightmargin=5pt,
    innerleftmargin=5pt,
}
\newenvironment{losung}{%
    \begin{mdframed}[style=losungstyle]
    \textbf{Lösung:} % "Solution:" in bold and italics
    \par\noindent % Start italicized text for the body
}{%
    \hfill $\blacksquare$ % Add the square symbol at the end
    \end{mdframed}
}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Example}
\section{Section One}
\begin{uebung}
    I am Uebung. Please write my solution.
\end{uebung}
\begin{losung}
    Hi I am Solution\footnote{I am footnote content.}
\end{losung}
\section{Section Two}
\end{document}


Did you test the code as it is shown in your question? I get two errors because packages/libraries are missing.

See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/314375/why-does-parbox-lose-footnotes?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C48.1428 and possibly https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/699729/utilizing-the-table-option-to-span-a-table-across-a-two-column-format-results/699747?r=SearchResults&s=3%7C0.0000#699747
